# Xpath Filtering a list and getting last element of a type

Tags: list, xslt, xpath

I get a file with video links of different movies that I want to extract. 
The video links are in a **@CAPTURE-0** element.
Sometimes I have 2 different links in the file for the same movie.

So what I want is for each different movie, extract the last link associated.

I have one table item, in this table I am applying some filters on the STEP and grouping by @ACTION attributes which contains the movie name.

My table will looks like something like this :

***The Hangover*** (contained in @ACTION)      |        ***link*** (value of the last @CAPTURE-0 for this movie)

***Star Wars*** (contained in @ACTION)         |        ***link*** (value of the last @CAPTURE-0 for this movie)

The file looks like :

```
...
<GENERIC_S 
     CAPTURE-0="VALUE1" >
        <STEP NUM="0" ID="3" ACTION="MOVIE1" RETURN=0/>
 </GENERIC_S>
 <GENERIC_S 
     CAPTURE-0="VALUE2">
        <STEP NUM="0" ID= "3" ACTION="MOVIE1" RETURN=0/>
 </GENERIC_S>
 <GENERIC_S 
     CAPTURE-0="VALUE3">
        <STEP NUM="0" ID= "3" ACTION="MOVIE2" RETURN=0/>
 </GENERIC_S>
 <GENERIC_S 
     CAPTURE-0="VALUE4">
        <STEP NUM="0" ID= "3" ACTION="MOVIE3" RETURN=0/>
 </GENERIC_S>
 <GENERIC_S 
     CAPTURE-0="VALUE5">
        <STEP NUM="0" ID= "4" ACTION="MOVIE3" RETURN=0/>
 </GENERIC_S>
...
```

So here I would like to extract only for ID=3 last @CAPTURE-0 element of each different @ACTION element :

VALUE2 for MOVIE1

VALUE3 for MOVIE2

VALUE4 for MOVIE3

So What I am applying looks like :

```
<item ......../>  <!-- this is the tab declaration -->
<rows path="*/STEP[@RETURN = 0]" group-by="@ACTION" title="@ACTION" >
<!-- filter that I want to apply to all my table, return must be 0 and group by action to group by movie name -->

<linkParam name="Movielink" path="//GENERIC_S[STEP/@ID=3][last()]/@CAPTURE-0"/>
<!-- here is where I want to return last @CAPTURE-0 element for each video which have a STEP  ID =3-->
```

When applying this in MovieLink : `//GENERIC_S[STEP/@ID=3][last()]/@CAPTURE-0`
I am able to get the last element of the list, but it's not taking in consideration the filter  `<rows path="*/STEP[@RETURN = 0]" group-by="@ACTION" title="@ACTION" >` it's returning me the same video link for all movies.

I hope this is clear on what I exactly want to do, 
I can provide more details if needed,

Thanks

Comment: This is a *grouping* question - do a search. Note that answers are different for XSLT10 or 2.0.